# Is there any way to find just the updated columns in an Oracle table

Tags: oracle

I have an oracle table with almost 800 columns and with 500k data. I have a requirement where i need to get only the updated columns of a record rather than the 800 columns of the updated record. Is there any way to pull out only the updated columns in a record? Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Diya

Comment: There is nothing inherent in the table or the data dictionary.  You'd have to create an audit/logging mechanism of your own (read: on-update trigger)  How far back in history would you need to check?  What if a column is updated multiple times during the 'audit period'?  Also, a table with 800 columns is _suggestive_ (not proven) of being rather poorly designed.  This many columns is often the result of not designing to 3d Normal Form.

Comment: define what you mean by 'the updated record'

Comment: Thanks for your reply EdStevens. I need not to check back. I need to check for only the updates on that table. And most importantly, I have to concentrate on 80 columns out of 800 for any updates and pull those colums which got updated.

Comment: @Diya looks like you need to normalize your table first which might increase performance and would be easier to track changes in resulting tables. Are you using any ETL tool to load this table? Most of the ETL tools have CDC (change data capture) mechanism which could be used in your case.

Answer (score 0):

800 columns is a little crazy, but, I dunno... I suppose such a table could exist.

You could start with a trigger.  In the trigger you can compare the ":new.col_name" vs ":old.col_name", but writing 800 of those is cumbersome.  "IF UPDATING("COL_NAME")" can be used; HOWEVER, this will return true even if the value isn't changing.  The UPDATING function is a test to see if the column was part of the update statement (it may or may not contain a different value than the old value).

So, to test if actually changed, you have to use the :new and :old objects and do a compare.  Oracle doesn't provide a slick reflective way to compare these as a collection, so good ol brute force must be used.

What you could do, is generate code with code.  Write a script with a select statement against all_tab_columns that'll generate the compare statements and other code lines you need for every column, then dump the output into trigger.  Use dbms_output.put_line to spit out the code that you want.

Write a cursor select like so (this off the cuff, you'll have to work the coding out):

```
SELECT 
  'IF (:new.'||column_name||' <> :old.'||atc.column_name||') THEN' as my_ifstmt 
FROM
  all_tab_columns atc
WHERE
  atc.owner = 'MYSCHEMA'
  AND atc.table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
```

Dump the results with dbms_output.put_line along with a statement to insert the result into an audit table or whatever it is you want to do:

```
dbms_output.put_line(my_cursor.my_ifstmt);
dbms_output.put_line('INSERT INTO my_audit_table... bla bla bla');
dbms_output.put_line("END IF;")
```

Put that all in your cursor loop.  No, that code is not complete nor functional yet, but it is the approach I might use given your limited requirements description.  Try to put some of this together and I can add more.

Comment: Thank you Somuch ! i would like to try this.